# Delphi: TStringList does not understand BOM?

Tags: delphi, filestream, decoding, stringstream

Does TStringList not understand BOM?

```
Tf1 := TFileStream.Create(LIGALOG+'liga.log',fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyNone);

str:=tstringlist.Create;
str.LoadFromStream(tf1);

String1:='FStream '+inttostr(tf1.Size)+'/ String: '+(str.Text);
```

If a text file is saved in UTF-8 +BOM then `Str.Count=0; Str.Text=''`. Without BOM all is OK.
 Is it normal?

Comment: which version of delphi are you using?

Comment: If you are using D2009 or later (IIRC, you are on D2010): Are you sure the file isn't defect?

Comment: -1. maxfax, downvoted not for spite, but because your question is really only useful if you clarify your delphi version.  please update and edit your question and in future, include delphi versions always.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're using a version of Delphi prior to 2009, it doesn't support Unicode and the BOM is meaningless to TStringList.

If you're using D2009 or higher (which support Unicode), you can use the overloaded `TStringList.LoadFromStream(Stream: TStream; Encoding: TEncoding)`if you know ahead of time what the encoding is; if you don't, the RTL will try to figure it out using `TEncoding.GetBufferEncoding`. You can see the Delphi XE documentation on the topic [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Classes.TStrings.LoadFromStream)

If you don't know ahead of time, and the RTL isn't able to figure it out from the content, you can always read the BOM yourself from the stream, and then set the `Stream.Position` to just after the BOM and load the `TStringList` from that position with the decoding you determine yourself from that BOM.

Also, creating a `TFileStream` simply to then load into a `TStringList` is a waste; `TStringList.LoadFromFile` will handle the file itself, and is a lot less code if that's all you're going to do with the `TStream`.

EDIT: After your comment, I thought I'd include a list of the BOMs I'm familiar with - there may be more I'm not aware of:

```
$00 $00 $FE $FF  UTF-32, big-endian (bytes must be swapped for Windows)
$FE $FF $00 $00  UTF-32, little-endian
$FF $FE          UTF-16 2 byte chars little-endian
$FE $FF          UTF-16 2 byte big-endian 
$EF $BB $BF      Unicode UTF-8 (must be decoded before using Unicode data)
```

(For future reference: You should indicate in either the tags or the text of your question which version of Delphi you're using, as there are differences in the VCL and RTL between them. When it comes to things like Unicode/BOM type questions, these differences are extremely important.)

Comment: Encoding was strange, not UTF-8 +/-BOM, Unicode, ANSI. So when I loaded FileStream to StringList I got nothing, 0.

Comment: when the `Encoding` parameter is nil (which it is when calling the older `LoadFrom...()` methods), then `GetBufferEncoding()` already checks for recognized BOMs when looking at the data.

Comment: @Remy: I said that in the last part of the second paragraph. 'the RTL will try to figure it out using TEncoding.GetBufferEncoding.'

Comment: you did not make it clear that `GetBufferEncoding()` will actually read (and discard) the BOM, though.

Comment: @Remy, thanks for the clarification. :) I'll remember that for future reference.